How do I get the Game Booster icon to show up for my Android game?
For most games on my Samsung S23 when you swipe up for the bottom menu while the game is running there's an extra fourth button on the left, which takes you to a Game Booster configuration menu.
I followed these Google instructions to implement support for Game Mode, but it still didn't make the Game Booster icon show up in my app.
https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/adpf/gamemode/gamemode-api
My game uses Vulkan instead of OpenGL if that would make a difference, but I thought the XML changes referenced above would make it work.
How do I get the Game Booster icon to show up in my app?

Does the game mode configuration show up on devices from other OEMs?

It shows up on the Pixel 8 Pro, but not Xaomi 13 or Samsung S23. I don't have any other phones to test with.
